# Signature field overlapping the content

Tags: html, css, laravel, dompdf

I want to convert html to pdf using domPDF in laravel.The program is generating letter with signature field.My issue is when the content is longer then the page.The content is overlapping the signature field.How to fix this issue?at least the the last paragraph  automaticly move to another page and make the signature in every page

this is the current 
[pdf result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FIFMz.png)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    {{-- <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="{{asset('/plugins/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css')}}"> --}}
    <title>Notulensi</title>
    <style>
        body {
            background: white;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body style="padding-left:20px;padding-right:20px;">
    <div class="container">
        <div style="align-content: center;text-align:center; ">
            <table width=100% style="margin-left:10px;">
                <tr>
                    <td width="10%"></td>
                    <td width="10%" align="center">
                        <div>
                            <img style="box-shadow: none;border-radius:none;width:100px;height:110px;"
                                src="{{ URL::asset('/images/logo.jpg')}}">
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td width="80%" align="center" style="text-align: center;align-content: center;">
                        <div style="text-align: center;align-content: center;">
                            <p style="line-height:0.5px;font-weight:bold; font-size:14;">PEMERINTAH KOTA MADIUN</p>
                            <p style="line-height:0.5px;font-weight:bolder;font-size:16;">SEKRETARIAT DAERAH</p>
                            <p style="font-size:14px;line-height:0.5px;">Jalan Pahlawan Nomor. 37 Madiun, Kode Pos :
                                63116
                                Jawa Timur
                            </p>
                            <p style="font-size:14px;line-height:1px;">Telepon ( 0351 ) 462756 Fax (0351) 457331</p>
                            <p style="font-size:14px;line-height:1px;">Website http://www.madiunkota.go.id</p>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
        <hr style="border:1px solid black;margin-top:0;line-height: 0%;">
        <h3 style="text-align: center">NOTULEN</h3>
        <table style="width:100%;">
            <tr>
                <td><label>Sidang/Rapat </label></td>
                <td>: {{ $t->judul_rapat }}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><label>Hari/Tanggal</label>
                </td>
                <td> : {{ explode(" ",$t->start)[0] }}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><label>Waktu Sidang </label>
                </td>
                <td> : {{ date('H:i',strtotime($t->start))}}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="vertical-align: top;"><label>Acara </label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    @foreach ($acara as $key => $item)
                    <li style="list-style: none;margin-top:0px;margin-bottom:0px;">{{ $key+1 }} -
                        {{ ucwords(strtolower($item->nama)) }}
                    </li>
                    @endforeach

                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Pimpinan Sidang/Rapat</td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><label>Ketua</label>
                </td>
                <td> : {{ ucwords(strtolower($data->nama_pimpinan)) }}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><label>Sekretaris</label>
                </td>
                <td> : {{ ucwords(strtolower($data->nama_sekretaris)) }}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><label>Pencatat</label>
                </td>
                <td> : {{ ucwords(strtolower($data->nama_notulen)) }}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="vertical-align: top;">Peserta Sidang/Rapat
                </td>
                <td>
                    &nbsp;
                    @foreach ($p as $key=>$item)

                    <li style="list-style: none;margin-top:0px;margin-bottom:0px;">
                        {{ ucwords(strtolower($item->nama))}}
                    </li>
                    @endforeach
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="vertical-align: top;"><label>Kegiatan</label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    &nbsp;
                    @foreach ($kegiatan as $key => $item)
                    <li style="list-style: none;margin-top:0px;margin-bottom:0px;">{{ $key+1 }} -
                        {{ ucwords(strtolower($item->nama)) }}
                    </li>
                    @endforeach
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <div style="font-size:14px;text-align:justify;align-content:center;">
            1. Kata Pembuka :
            {!! $data->kata_pembuka !!}
            2. Pembahasan :
            {!! $data->hasil_rapat !!}
            3. Peraturan :
            {!! $data->peraturan !!}
        </div>
    </div>
    <div style="position: absolute;bottom:2px;right:2px;width:200px;text-align:center;font-size:12px;">
        <p style="font-weight:bold;">PIMPINAN SIDANG/RAPAT</p>
        <p style="font-weight:bold;">NAMA JABATAN</p>
        <br>
        <p style="text-decoration:underline;font-weight:bold">{{ $data->nama_pimpinan }}</p>
        <p style="font-weight:bold">{{ $data->nip_pimpinan }}</p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Set `margin-bottom` for body equal to the height of signature area elsewhere the absolute positioned element always overlaps other elements.

Comment: who do i make the signature field constantly on the bottom of the page when the content is longer than the page and automaticly add another page?

Comment: absolute position is against the whole document in HTML and is not fixed (sticky) in the bottom of screen. If you want the signature on every page I have no idea (you might need to switch to header and footer tricks). But if you need a single singnature at the end of document, an absolute div will be enough while you consider an equal margin in the bottom of webpage.